# PHP- Array combine not working properly

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do array combine, but it is not working properly. I have one array called `$models` which consits of objects and it looks like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => Comment {#377 ▶}
  1 => Thumb {#378 ▶}
  2 => View {#379 ▶}
  3 => Vote {#380 ▶}
]
```

Then since I am passing it to another function, I am adding one more object as an element like this:

```
 array_push($models, new User);
```

And then I get an array that looks like this:

```
 array:5 [▼
  0 => Comment {#377 ▶}
  1 => Thumb {#378 ▶}
  2 => View {#379 ▶}
  3 => Vote {#380 ▶}
  4 => User {#399 ▶}
]
```

I am then doing foreach loop to get the total count in the DB for each model like this:

```
foreach ($models as $model){
  $modelCounts[] = $model->count();
}
```

My `$modelCounts` than looks like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => 19
  1 => 22
  2 => 15
  3 => 17
  4 => 3
]
```

And then I am trying to do array_combine so that my objects are keys and the counts are values like this:

```
 $result = array_combine($models, $modelCounts);
```

But something is not working right because when I do `dd($result);` I get:

```
  array:1 [▼
  "[]" => 3
]
```

But when I do it the other way around like this:

```
$result = array_combine($modelCounts, $models);
```

It works fine and I get:

```
array:5 [▼
  19 => Comment {#377 ▶}
  22 => Thumb {#378 ▶}
  15 => View {#379 ▶}
  17 => Vote {#380 ▶}
  3 => User {#399 ▶}
]
```

But I need it the other way around and not like this.

Comment: You mean you want your keys to be PHP objects? That's not possible. They either have to be integers or strings. You cannot make an object or an array a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects can't be used as key for associative arrays, only scalar values are allowed.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

Comment: Is there a way I can somehow get objects names as keys then?

Comment: Usually, you have an array with your objects. If you really need a separate array with the lengths, you use a second array with the same keys as in your first array - exaclty what you have above. But why a second array with the length if your object can return these first hand very well.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why the first `array_combine()` fails is that an objcect cannot be usead as an array key.
You may want to create an array containing classes names first by using `get_class()` to get class's name and then combine it with `$modelCounts`

It should look something like this

```
foreach ($models as $model){
  $modelNames[] = get_class($model);
}

$result = array_combine($modelNames, $modelCounts);
```

Comment: You're assuming an awful lot. Two problems with this. First, what if all of those objects are the same class? Second, there is no function `get_name`. Did you mean [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)?

Comment: Yep, I ment `get_class`. I know it's not the best solution, espacially when classes names occur more than 1 time, but on my defense: it's enough for the example provided by @Marco

Comment: It's not really a solution at all tho. By having the same key over and over it will condense the array. Check out this example https://3v4l.org/K1s7A

Comment: I know it will, but for the example provided by Marco no such thing was happening.